# How do I code what my mouse click? I managed to do e.get() by using user to type but now, I want to do a mouse version

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing a GUI Tkinter project. Currently. I am able to display the excel file on my GUI via treeview function. I want to code in a way that my mouse click for example, when row 1 is clicked, it will read row1, column 2 box and look for the file in the documents based on the word in row1 x column 2 box and plot some graphs which is completed/ not important, or when row x is left-clicked, lock in row x X column 2 to find the name and search for it in my documents file.
I want to code the e.get() but mouse click version.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/njj95/Documents/"+e1.get()+".csv")
```

What I have tried so far is left click and right click.

```
def leftClick(event):
    print("left")    
def rightClick(event):
    print("right")
my_tree.bind("<Button-1>",leftClick)
my_tree.bind("<Button-3>",rightClick)
```

What I have done previously was to user user to enter name and continues from there. Now I want to upgrade my GUI by just clicking  the list of usernames instead of user typing in the username.
Previously, my code was

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/njj95/Documents/"+e1.get()+".csv")
```

The e1.get() is entered by user.

[image: This is the user type in version GUI]

[image: This is an exact copy and paste from an excel file]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event.y` to find which row is clicked inside `leftClick()` function, then use `.item()` to get the asset ID value from the returned values:

```
def leftClick(event):
    # find which row is clicked
    row = event.widget.identify_row(event.y)
    if row:
        # get the asset ID (first value in "values")
        asset_id = event.widget.item(row)["values"][0]
        print(asset_id)
    else:
        print("No record clicked")

my_tree.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
```